# Import Excel data to Access through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub AccImport()
    Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbFileName As String
    Dim dbRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim xRow As Long, xColumn As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Go to the worksheet containing the records you want to transfer.
    Worksheets("Completed").Activate

    'Determine the last row of data based on column A.
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Create the connection to the database.
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection

    'Define the database file name
    dbFileName = "C:/..."

    'Define the Provider and open the connection.
    With dbConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbFileName & _
                    ";Persist Security Info=False;"
        .Open dbFileName
    End With

    'Create the recordset
    Set dbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    dbRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    dbRecordset.Open Source:="Resolution", _
                              ActiveConnection:=dbConnection, _
                              CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
                              LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
                              Options:=adCmdTable

    'Loop thru rows & columns to load records from Excel to Access.
    'Assume row 1 is the header row, so start at row 2.
    For xRow = 2 To LastRow
        dbRecordset.AddNew
        'Assume this is an 26-column (field) table starting with column A.
        For xColumn = 1 To 26
            dbRecordset(Cells(1, xColumn).Value) = Cells(xRow, xColumn).Value
        Next xColumn
        dbRecordset.Update
    Next xRow

    'Close the connections.
    dbRecordset.Close
    dbConnection.Close

    'Release Object variable memory.
    Set dbRecordset = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
    'Optional:
    'Clear the range of data (the records) you just transferred.
    Range("A2:Z" & LastRow).ClearContents
 End Sub
```

When I tried exporting the data its giving me error in as:

> Error 3265. Item cannot be found in the collection.

I'm unable to export the data it's giving me error in the line

```
dbRecordset(Cells(1, xColumn).Value) = Cells(xRow, xColumn).Value
```

... Any Ideas

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it like that. Use `docmd.transferSpreadsheet`

One line will import the data into Access. You will need to add the reference `Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library` to be able to use `docmd`. Or just run it from Access

So it will be something like `docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "AccessTableName", "FullFileName",true,"Range"`

Replacing, `AccessTablename` with the name of the table you want to import to.
`FullFileName` with the full file name of the excel sheet. `Range` with the range excel sheet. You can remove `range` if you want to just copy all from Excel.

EDIT. Updated to open Access

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    appAccess.Visible = True

    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "FILENAME OF ACCESS DB"

    appAccess.docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "AccessTableName", "FullFileName", False
```

This will open the Access DB. Run the code and import the table.

Comment: Sam I want to export all the data of a sheet excluding the header..So in that case what would be the Range.. Can you please help..

Comment: If you do not want the headser change the `true` to `false`. That changes to not include the title rows

Comment: Its giving me error transferspreadsheet isn't available now. is there anything I have to do now, I have checked all references from Available reference

Comment: Looking at it you may have to open the Access database first through VBA. I will look into it and will update my answer once I have done it

Comment: Sure.. Thank you Sam.. Will be waiting for your Response.

Comment: I've updated. Try that. You will need to then open the db again to see it

Comment: Sam , I do not wish to import anything from the database instead I would like to export data from Excel to access.

Comment: The function is calling import because it is being run from Access. So it opens the Access and then Imports from Excel. It is the same thing as Exporting from Excel to Access except Access is running the code so it would be an Import

Comment: Ok Sam, It's working for me.  I found the reason why it is throwing me the error because out of 26 columns only 18 are filled and rest 8 are empty. because of its unable to execute.  Can you please update the code that I have.

Comment: What if I dont want the database to open?? I dont want it to be opened and shown to everyone. Also Is there a way to export only few sheets and not all of them.

Comment: If you do not want the db to be shown to everyone change `appAccess.Visible = True` to `appAccess.Visible = False` And add `AppAccess.quit` at the end of the code.From what I see it should only export what ever sheet is visible. That is how it is working for me. However if you want to export more than one. You should do some code to open the workbook. Copy the sheet you want to a new book. Save the new book and use that book to import to Access. Then delete the created book.

Comment: FWIW, I think your original code would work if you altered it to ignore blank headers.

Comment: Exactly Rory, But can you please help me with that altered code to ignore headers?

Comment: Are your headers in the first row? And also why wouldnt you want headers?